# Call a Sub Window In Point Of Sale interface through button in Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo

I need to ask if there is way to call a child window in the 'Point Of Sale' interface in Odoo-8. My scenario is that I have a button on the POS interface and I need to call sub/child window through that button . The window will have some buttons and some textboxes to take input from the user. I can show pop_up form with Error message on it. But I need to call a form with fields and button. Any help or guidance will be appreciated.
Thanks n Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to create widget for that.
So basically create one template file and js file to handle button click and other operations.

How to create widget and its basic: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html

For example see pos_discount module.

Feel free to ask if any issue arises.

Comment: i have created the button on the pos interface, now I need to call a popup window with textboxes and button on it.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done be making the button call a function which returns a ir.action.act_window.

Example from [base_export_languages](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_export_language.py)

```
return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'base.language.export',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'res_id': this.id,
            'views': [(False, 'form')],
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

This will open a window with a model. You probably need to make a new model where you keep new data and views. Also you can specify view with `'view_id': view_id,` but keep in mind that view_id must be a id as integer.

Hopefully this will be helpful to you.

Comment: but i need to call that view in client side interface i.e. "Point Of Sale"